# Azure Webjobs Service bus topic Not logging function calls

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a sample WebJob I wrote which uses a service bus.  My data ingestion layer is all SB queue that then publish data onto topics.  I can see all of my Queue functions getting invoked and working with provided text writer as a logger, but not my topic based functions.  I can see them getting invoked by the log and output can be obtained using console.writeline.  Is there something else I need to do for topics?

topic function

```
 public static void HandleContactAssigned(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(ContactAssingedTopic, "sub_contact_assigned")] NotifyAssigmentInfo message,
            TextWriter writer
            )
        {
            writer.WriteLine("HandleContactAssinged Called");
            Console.WriteLine("called HandleContactAssinged");
        }
```

WebJobs Console output

[04/16/2015 16:28:03 > e1254f: INFO] called HandleContactAssinged
[04/16/2015 16:28:03 > e1254f: INFO] Executing: 'MessageFunctions.HandleContactAssigned' because New service bus message detected on 'int_contact_assgined/Subscriptions/sub_contact_assigned'.
[04/16/2015 16:28:03 > e1254f: INFO] called HandleContactAssinged

As you can see the function gets called but no of the normal monitoring/logging works

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... That should work. Make sure you have set the AzureWebJobsDashboard connectionstring in your WebJob or the Azure portal.

You can also look at the following sample as an example.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus

Comment: Yea it does work for all other functions.  This is my first topic function and it shows up on the functions page but doesn't show invocation statistics or the logging.

Comment: Is there another function by the same name? Is the storage account associated with the dashboardconnection used by another WebJob?